# Error when deleting indexeddb database in Google Chrome 21 problems

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

Since today I've started getting errors when I try to delete IndexedDB database in Google Chrome version 21.
When i run the command for deleting database:

```
window.webkitIndexedDB.deleteDatabase(dbName);
```

The following event fires:

```
IDBVersionChangeEvent
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
clipboardData: undefined
currentTarget: IDBVersionChangeReques
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 2
returnValue: true
srcElement: IDBVersionChangeRequest
target: IDBVersionChangeRequest
timeStamp: 1343929274696
type: "blocked"
version: ""
```

Additional info: I am accessing the IndexedDB from web workers and from window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the accessing the database from the web workers. In this line of code:

```
database.close();//closing the database
self.close();//closing the web worker
```

There is probably some bug in Google chrome if database closing needs more time than usual and you close the web worker, then the database is locked when you try to delete it afterwards.

I've fixed the problem by not closing the web worker and let it stay in idle mode.

Answer (score 4):

It means there is an open connection to that database somewhere. It could be in a different tab than the one that's calling deleteDatabase.  That connection received a versionchange event notifying it that a call to deleteDatabase had been made and that it needs to close.

You can add such a handler when the database is opened:

```
request = indexeddb.open("dbname");
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  db = event.target.result;
  db.onversionchange = function(event) {
    event.target.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: onversionchange doesn't fire when i try to delete the database

Comment: That's probably a bug then. If you have a simple repro case you can file it at http://crbug.com/new

Comment: Yes there is probably bug in google chrome when accessing db from web workers I've posted the solution below.

Comment: This was the solution to my problem.  I am creating a Chrome App, I have the background script and foreground script and need to access IndexedDB from both of them.  I was having a a problem deleting, which originates in the foreground script, but adding this code worked wonders! The onversionchange fired in the background script.  Thanks!